# How to fix pgAdmin 4 not importing my csv file?

Tags: postgresql, csv, pgadmin-4

I have a csv file on my computer that I am trying to import into a postgres DB using pgAdmin 4. I am using the import tool, am able to find the correct csv file in the import/export dialog box, and when I click "Ok" I get a message saying "Import/Export job has been created" and then nothing.

[image: Import Dialogue Box]

[image: "job created" message bottom right]

Is there a solution to this? Or is there an alternative way to load the csv file into my tables?

Comment: Have you tried using `COPY yourtable FROM '/home/thulain...'`?

Comment: Yes. I am unable to as I am not a superuser, and I am unable to alter myself to a superuser.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue "Import/Export job created". I thought maybe its a MAC issue. Anyway, my work-around on the `COPY` is put the file in the applications folder, it's the only folder postgreSQL is able to read (at least in my case) without being a superuser.